# Why is the Codepen embed <div> calculating height taller than child iframe? How can I correct this?

Tags: html, css, iframe, embed

I am using the codepen html embed code with a specified `data-height="600"`px.

Here's [a link](http://codepen.io/ianseabrook/pen/b32a1f333c7328c01536b6e16f5ddcc6?editors=110#0)!

[Debug view](http://s.codepen.io/ianseabrook/debug/b32a1f333c7328c01536b6e16f5ddcc6).

Codepen is replacing the fallback `<p>` with:

```
<div>
<iframe>
</iframe>
</div>
```

The wrapper `<div>`'s height is calculating **4px** taller than the `<iframe>`. This is creating unwanted whitespace (styled green here) between the content edge and any `box-shadow` I might apply.

1. Why?
2. How can I override this?

Comment: How does that codepen have anything to do with your question, please edit!

Comment: I have added a link to the debug view. The area in question is the green between the embed and the red `<li>` border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iframe is an inline element, which, when displayed inside a block, leaves space below it for the descender, because the bottom of the iframe is aligned with the baseline. (This is the same behaviour as `img`).

Solution: add either `display:block` or `vertical-align:top` to the style for the iframe.

Comment: Felt sure I'd tried that already but clearly not.  Amazing how helpful a fresh pair of eyes can be. Thanks!